# Let $A=B=\Bbb Z$, $\phi:n\mapsto 2\cdot n$. Show $\phi$ is 1:1. Show $\not\exists$ a group hom $\psi:B\to A$ s.t. $\psi\circ\phi={\rm id}_A$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, group-homomorphism

I am trying to solve.

> Take $A = B = \mathbb{Z}$ and $\phi$ given by $n \mapsto 2 \cdot n$. Show that $\phi$ is injective. Show that there does not exist a group homomorphism $\psi: B \to A$ such that $\psi \circ \phi = \mathrm{id}_A$.

The proof of injectivity seems straightforward, but I'm unsure if my approach is valid.

> Suppose $\phi(n) = \phi(m)$ for $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then. $2n = 2m$, so $n = m$.

The problem here is: I'm working in the world of the integers, but I've multiplied both sides by $\frac{1}{2}$, which is not an integer. Is this allowed? Alternatively, I could rearrange and prove that $2(n-m) = 0$ and argue that because $\mathbb{Z}$ has no zero divisors, $n-m = 0$, so $n=m$. But I haven't proven that $\mathbb{Z}$ has no zero divisors and am not sure how to prove that from first principles.

As for the second condition:

> Suppose for the sake of contradiction that there exists such a homomorphism $\psi$. Then $(\psi \circ \phi)(1) = 1$. Define $\psi(1) = g$. Then
> $$ 
> 1 = (\psi \circ \phi)(1) = \psi(\phi(1)) = \psi(2) = \psi(1 + 1) = \psi(1) + \psi(1) = g + g = 2g. 
> $$
> But $2g = 1$, so $g = \frac{1}{2} \not \in \mathbb{Z}$, so we have a contradiction.

My worry again is that I've multiplied by a non-integer.

Comment: (1) You are not "multiplying both sides by $\frac{1}{2}$", you are cancelling: $2n=2m$ means $2(n-m)=0$, which means $n-m=0$. But even if you are, it doesn't matter: an equality in $\mathbb{Z}$ implies one in $\mathbb{Q}$, where it *fails*. So no equality to being with. (2) Usually, with group homomorphisms, it is far better to prove injectivity by considering the **kernel**: show that $\phi(n)=0$ implies $n=0$ and you are done. (3) You haven't "multiplied by a noninteger"; you have observed that $1\notin 2\mathbb{Z}$, but $2g\in2\mathbb{Z}$. This is a valid group-theoretic/integral argument.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Can you explain what you mean by "no equality to begin with"? I'm not totally sure I follow.

Comment: **If** you have an equality in $X=Y$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, then this is also true in $\mathbb{Q}$. So if from $X=Y$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ you conclude an absurdity, that means that $X\neq Y$ in $\mathbb{Q}$, and that means that you did not, in fact, have $X=Y$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. In other words: since "$X=Y$ in $\mathbb{Z}$" implies "$X=Y$ in $\mathbb{Q}$", the contrapositive tells you that "$X\neq Y$ in $\mathbb{Q}$" implies "$X\neq Y$ in $\mathbb{Z}$"... which is what you want to conclude.

Comment: There is nothing wrong about "leaving" whatever universe you are working with in order to deduce things, as long as you are careful in making sure your conclusions also "import back in." For example, the first proof of the Prime Number Theorem, which is a question about number theory (or perhaps about real analysis) was solved by "leaving"  the integers and working in the complex numbers.